# How to use passed data from nodejs to ejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

So I have this data from nodejs:

```
const testData = {
signature: {
     image: `data:image/png;base64,${base64}`,
     name: 'Test Name',
     tag: 'Test Tag',
   },
};
```

and then on my ejs, I am displaying the image by this:

```
<img src="<%= signature.image %>" />
```

the problem is ejs is not rendering my image because I think the `<%= %>` syntax is messing up with ejs.

Comment: Try `<%- signature.image %>` instead. the `=` escapes the string whereas `-` does not.

Comment: Try `<%= testData.signature.image %>` it will work

Comment: How you are sending the `testData` to the ejs file?

Comment: I am passing it by `const html = await ejs.renderFile('./test.ejs', testData, { async: true });`

Comment: @Molda still didnt work

Comment: @NikhilSavaliya didnt work too

Comment: What is the output of `ejs.renderFile`?